# ループ構造におけるフラグ判定の正しい使い方

Tags: javascript

提示コードですがテトリスでブロックが一列揃ったら点滅(エフェクト)して消えてラインを詰めるという処理なのですがこの際にフラグという処理の作り方をしているのですがこれは正しいのでしょうか？　提示コードのコンストラクタ部の `/* ### エフェクト ###*/`,`/*## 削除 ##*/`部の `bool`型変数のフラグの多さが気がかりです。

利用ライブラリ: https://p5js.org/

Game.js

```
      // ################################ エフェクト ################################ 
      Effect()
      {
            if( (this.clearLine.length > 0) && (this.isEffect == true) )
            {

                  this.blink_Time += deltaTime;
                  if(this.blink_Time > BLINKING_INTERVAL)
                  {
                        this.isBlink = !this.isBlink;
                        this.blink_Time = 0;

                        this.blinkCount++;
                        if(this.blinkCount > BLICK_COUNT)
                        {
                              this.blinkCount = 0;
                              this.isEffect = false;
                              this.isNewBlock = true;
                              this.isBlink = false;
                              this.isShiftLine = true;
                              this.setReset();
                        }
                  }
            }
            else
            {
                  this.isPutBlock = false;
            }
      }

      // ################################ ライン 詰める ################################ 
      ShiftLine(stage)
      {
            if(this.isShiftLine == true)
            {
                  let count = 0;
                  for(let y = 0; y < STAGE_HEIGHT; y++)
                  {
                        count = 0;
                        for(let x = 0; x < STAGE_WIDTH; x++)
                        {
                              if( (stage[y][x] != WALL) && (stage[y][x] != NONE) )
                              {
                                    count++;
                              }
                        }

                        if(count == LINE)
                        {
                              for(let x = 1; x < STAGE_WIDTH; x++)
                              {
                                    for(let yy = y; yy > 0; yy--)
                                    {
                                          stage[yy][x] = stage[yy - 1][x];

                                    }
                              }
                        }
                  }

                  this.isShiftLine = false;
            }
      }      
      // ################################ ライン削除 取得 ################################ 
      ClearLine(stage)
      {
            if(this.isPutBlock == true && this.isCearLine == false )
            {
                  for(let y = 0; y < STAGE_HEIGHT; y++)
                  {
                        let count = 0;
                        let temp = new Array(0);
                        for(let x = 1; x < STAGE_WIDTH; x++)
                        {
                              if( (stage[y][x] != WALL) && (stage[y][x] != NONE) )
                              {
                                    temp.push(new Vector(x,y));
                                    count++;
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                    break;
                              }
                        }

                        if(count == LINE)
                        {
                              this.clearLine.push(y);
                        }
                        
                  }
                  
                  if(this.clearLine.length > 0)
                  {
                        this.isEffect = true;
                        this.isCearLine = true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        this.isPutBlock == false;
                        this.isNewBlock = true;
                  }
            }

            this.Effect();    //エフェクト
      }


      // ################################ コンストラクタ ################################ 
      constructor()
      {            
            /* ########## 現在　ブロック ########## */
            this.nowBlock = 
            [
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0]
            ];

      
                   
            /* ########## 次の　ブロック ########## */
            this.nextBlock = 
            [
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0]
            ];

            /* ########## ブロック ########## */
            this.blockNumber;                                                       //現在のブロック
            this.nextBlockNumber = Math.floor(random(2,7)) - BLOCK_COLOR;           //次のブロック

            this.position;
            
            /* ########## 落下 ########## */
            this.down_Time = 0;
            this.downHit = false;
            this.put_Time = 0;

            /* ########## 削除ライン ########## */
            this.isPutBlock = false;      //ブロックを置くかどうか？
            this.isNewBlock = true;       //新しいブロックを出すかどうか？
            this.isCearLine = false;      //詰めるラインを算出するかどか？
            this.isShiftLine = false;     //ラインを詰めるかどうか？

            /* ########## 入力  ########## */
            this.isPushSpaceKey = false;
            this.isHoldSpaceKey = false;
            this.isPushRightKey = false;
            this.isHoldRightKey = false;
            this.isPushLeftKey = false;
            this.isHoldLeftKey = false;                        

            /* ########## エフェクト ########## */
            this.isEffect = false;
            this.isBlink = false;
            this.blink_Time = 0;
            this.blinkCount = 0;
            this.nowDeleteLine = false;
            this.clearLine = [];      //削除ライン


            /* ########## 回転 ########## */
            this.rotate = 0;
            this.isRotate = false;

            this.setReset();  //ブロック生成
      }

      // ################################ ブロック生成 ################################ 
      setReset()
      {
            if( (this.isNewBlock == true) && (this.isEffect == false) )
            {
                  this.rotate = 0;
                  this.clearLine.length = 0;
                  this.isCearLine = false;
                  this.isEffect = false;
                  this.isPutBlock = false;
                  this.position = new Vector(START_BLOCK_POSITION_X,START_BLOCK_POSITION_Y);
                  this.blockNumber = this.nextBlockNumber;
                  this.nextBlockNumber = Math.floor(random(2,7)) - BLOCK_COLOR;

//                  this.blockNumber = Math.floor(random(2,7)) - BLOCK_COLOR;
                  


                  //ブロック クリア
                  for(let y = 0; y < BLOCK_HEIGHT; y++)
                  {
                        for(let x = 0; x < BLOCK_WIDTH; x++)
                        {
                              this.nowBlock[y][x] = 0;
                        }
                  }

                  //ブロック設定
                  for(let y = 0; y < BLOCK_HEIGHT; y++)
                  {
                        for(let x = 0; x < BLOCK_WIDTH; x++)
                        {
                              this.nowBlock[y][x] = blockPattern[this.blockNumber][y][x];
                        }
                  }
                  
                  this.isNewBlock = false;
            }

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分はテトリスの回転を再現したのですがこのサイトにより配列の左上に詰めるのではなくルールによって分けれており各ブロックに対する個別の処理を記述する必要があるとのことなので解決しました。

テトリスの回転ルール https://tetrisch.github.io/main/srs.html